# Como utilizar o decorator @registry() do tsyringe corretamente

Tags: typescript, typeorm, tsyringe

Olá, estou tentando utilizar o decorator [@registry()](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe#registry) do tsyringe conforme a documentação:

1. fiz a instalação das dependências e configurei o arquivo `tsconfig.json`:

```shell
yarn add -D reflect-metadata && yarn add tsyringe
```

```js
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true, 
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": { "$/*": ["./src/*"] },
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "ts-node": { "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register", "dotenv/config"] },
  "include": ["tsconfig.json", "package.json", "**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["/node_modules/*", "/dist/*"]
}
```

2. importei no meu arquivo inicial o reflect metadata assim:

```
// index.ts
import 'reflect-metadata';
import env from './env';
import { dataSource } from './infra/typeorm';
import logger from './logger'; // logging usando o winston
import app from './main';

dataSource.initialize() // inicialização do TypeORM
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(env.app.port, () => { // inicialização do Express
      logger.info(`running on port ${env.app.port}`);
    })
  })
  .catch((e: Error) => {
    logger.error(e);
    process.exit(1)
  });
```

3. tenho as interfaces no meu domínio assim (juntei tudo pra minimizar):

```
import { AuthorizedHeader, Entity } from '../generics';
import { User } from '../models';

export interface IAddUserCase {
  add(data: IAddUserCase.Data): Promise<IAddUserCase.Result>;
};
export namespace IAddUserCase {
  export type Data = {
    headers: AuthorizedHeader;
    body: Omit<User, keyof Entity>;
  };
  export type Result = Omit<User, 'password'>;
}

export interface IAddUserTask {
  add(data: IAddUserTask.Data): Promise<IAddUserTask.Result>;
};
export namespace IAddUserTask {
  export type Data = Omit<User, keyof Entity>;
  export type Result = User;
}

export interface IAddUserRepo {
  add(data: IAddUserRepo.Data): Promise<IAddUserRepo.Result>;
};
export namespace IAddUserRepo {
  export type Data = User;
  export type Result = void;
}
```

4. tenho o "caso de uso" definido assim:

```
// $/presentation/cases/add-user.case.ts
import { IAddUserCase } from '$/domain/cases';
import { inject, injectable, registry } from 'tsyringe';
import { IAddUserTask } from '../tasks';

@injectable()
@registry([{ token: 'IAddUserCase', useClass: AddUserCase }])
export class AddUserCase implements IAddUserCase {
  constructor(
    @inject('IAddUserTask') readonly addUserTask: IAddUserTask
  ) { }

  async add(data: IAddUserCase.Data): Promise<IAddUserCase.Result> {
    return await this.addUserTask.add(data.body);
  }
};
```

5. e tenho as "tarefas" executadas no caso assim:

```
// $/data/tasks/add-user.task.ts
import crypto from 'crypto';
import { IAddUserTask } from '$/presentations/tasks';
import { inject, injectable, registry } from 'tsyringe';
import { IAddUserRepo } from '../repos';

@injectable()
@registry([{ token: 'IAddUserTask', useClass: AddUserTask }])
export class AddUserTask implements IAddUserTask {
  constructor(
    @inject('IAddUserRepo') readonly addUserRepo: IAddUserRepo
  ) { }

  async add(data: IAddUserTask.Data): Promise<IAddUserTask.Result> {
    return await this.addUserRepo.add({
      ...data,
      _uid: crypto.randomUUID(),
      _created: new Date()
    });
  }
}
```

6. e por ultimo tenho o repositório usando o TypeORM assim:

```
// $/infra/typeorm/repos/add-user.repo.ts
import { IAddUserRepo } from '$/data/repos';
import { injectable, registry } from 'tsyringe';
import { dataSource } from '../data-source';
import { UserEntity } from '../entities';

@injectable()
@registry([{ token: 'IAddUserRepo', useClass: TypeORMAddUserRepo }])
export class TypeORMAddUserRepo implements IAddUserRepo {
  async add(data: IAddUserRepo.Data): Promise<IAddUserRepo.Result> {
    await dataSource
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .insert()
      .into(UserEntity)
      .values(data)
      .execute();
  }
}
```

7. Então eu chamo o `container` do tsyringe na minha rota do express assim:

```
// main/routes/api/user.routes.ts
import { addUserValidator } from '$/infra/joi';
import { AddUserCase } from '$/presentations/cases';
import { Router } from 'express';
import { container } from 'tsyringe';

const userRoutes = Router();

userRoutes.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const data = await addUserValidator(req);
  const result = await container.resolve(AddUserCase).add(data);
  res.status(201).json(result);
});
```

8. E por final eu importo a rota na inicialização do express assim:

```
// main/index.ts
import express from 'express';
import 'express-async-errors';
import { corsMiddleware, errorHandlerMiddleware } from './middlewares';
import userRoutes from './routes/api/user.routes.ts';

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(corsMiddleware);
app.use('/api/user', userRoutes);
app.use(errorHandlerMiddleware);

export default app;
```

Teoricamente, com base na documentação, ao utilizar o decorator eu conseguiria resolver a classe `AddUserCase` sem problemas mas ao fazer uma requisição na rota eu recebo essa mensagem:

```shell
Error: Cannot inject the dependency "addUserTask" at position #0 of "AddUserCase" constructor. Reason:
    Attempted to resolve unregistered dependency token: "IAddUserTask"
    at /Users/leandro.gomes/dev/leandroluk/caas/api_auth/node_modules/tsyringe/dist/cjs/dependency-container.js:324:23
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/.../node_modules/tsyringe/dist/cjs/dependency-container.js:295:38
    at InternalDependencyContainer.construct (/Users/.../node_modules/tsyringe/dist/cjs/dependency-container.js:297:11)
    at InternalDependencyContainer.resolve (/Users/.../node_modules/tsyringe/dist/cjs/dependency-container.js:114:33)
    at /Users/.../src/main/routes/api/user.routes.ts:51:34
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/Users/.../src/main/routes/api/user.routes.ts:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor? gostaria de utilizar o tsyringe com os dacorators pois eu presumo que seja a forma mais simples de trabalhar com DI comparada a outras opções no mercado mas realmente não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Encontrei a solução para meu problema. Eu utilizo barrels no meu projeto como nos exemplos abaixo:

```
// $/infra/typeorm/repos
import * from './add-user.repo'
```

```
// $/infra/typeorm
import * from './repos'
```

```
// $/infra
import * from './typeorm'
```

O que faltava era que, no meu arquivo inicial da solução que eu fizesse a importação das camadas. Assim o NodeJS consegue resolver automaticamente todos os `@registry` utilizados no projeto:

```
import '$/data';
import '$/infra';
import { dataSource } from '$/infra/typeorm';
import '$/presentation';
import env from './env';
import logger from './logger';
import app from './main';

dataSource.initialize()
  .then(() => app.listen(env.app.port, () => {
    logger.info(`running on port ${env.app.port}`);
  }))
  .catch((e: Error) => logger.error(e) && process.exit(1));
```

> **Nota:** também configurei para que a lib 'reflect-metadata' seja importada préviamente através do ts-node assim:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": { "$/*": [ "./src/*" ] },
    ...
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "require": [ "tsconfig-paths/register", "dotenv/config", "reflect-metadata" ]
  },
  "include": [ "tsconfig.json", "package.json", "**/*.ts" ],
  "exclude": [ "/node_modules/*", "/dist/*" ]
}
```